# Linux read form serial port - fork workaround

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port

I'm trying to send data via serial port and receive the response. Currently I'm looping the interface physically to emulate the device.
first I do:

```
# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -echo
```

if I try to read after write, it doesn't print anything:

```
# echo "foo" > /dev/ttyUSB0; cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I have to fork the read before write to get the response.

```
# cat /dev/ttyUSB0 &
[1] 7881

# echo -ne "foo\xA\0"
foo
```

Is there a work around?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've got the correct read and write privileges for /dev/ttyUSB0. You simply need to have the `echo` running on one terminal:

```
echo -ne 'foo\xA\0' >  /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and the `cat` running on another terminal (use the `-v` option to make all characters readable):

```
cat -v /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The problem is, i have to run cat in the other terminal before running echo.

Am i missing something to be able to read right after write?